# Put local storage value in a text box with ionic and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

i'm developing an app on ionic framework i upload files to the server and get back the response and i save the file name in a `localstorage`. Now my problem is when the response is saved into `localstorage` i want to put the value in a textbox called `filename`. please how do i do it?

```
 function win(r) {
            //alert("Response =" + r.response);
            window.localStorage.setItem("picture",r.response)
            {$ionicLoading.hide();}
            $scope.filename = localStorage.getItem('picture');
            //console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            //console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            //console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }
```

HTML

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Fashion Line</span>
    <input name="filename" type="text" id="filenaname"  ng-model="filename" >
  </label>
```

Comment: What is specific problem? Show the textbox html. Are you using `ng-model`? Always provide a  [mcve]

Comment: What's the problem?  What does `console.log($scope.filename); says?

Comment: is `r.response` a string or an object?

Comment: a string that returns the response from the server

Comment: I think, it is not an issue with localStorage, it is issue with your angular code.  Are other model bindings are working?

Comment: Breaking the golden rule of always using an object in ng-model. If you have child scopes primitive bindings will be broken

Answer (score 0):

I don't know angular very well - but this seems like you are getting the response - putting it into local storage and then getting it out again from local storage to set the filename - all within one function.

you can simplfiy that by not getting the local storage item  for the file name - since it is in the same functiuon:

```
   window.localStorage.setItem("picture",r.response)
    {$ionicLoading.hide();}
    $scope.filename = r.response;
```

this means that you are both setting the loal storage item and the filnename with the same variable without the extra step of getting it out of local storage.